# When using yarn install the primary color of Nuxt/Vuetify is Black and White (Screenshot Attached)

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuetify.js, nuxt.js, yarnpkg

It should be look like this( It shows the primary color, I use npm install for this):
[(Staging Enviroment)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gCKG.png) (Click to see the image)

But when deployed thru prod(I use yarn install for this ):
[Prod Env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fAl2.png) (Click to see the image)

What seems to be the problem? I hope you can help me
I want to use yarn bcoz it is faster than npm

Comment: Welcome to SO. For us to help you faster, please post the code relevant to your problem and where exactly you get stuck. Following other guidelines in the [how to ask a question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will also improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Actually i dont have problem with the code its just that when i use yarn install vs npm install. i use nuxt with vuetify upgraded to 2.0. I dont know exactly which part causes it.